# Configure description for package published to the GitHub Packages Gradle registry

Tags: gradle, github-package-registry

When publishing a package to the GitHub Packages Gradle registry, the resulting package's description is empty.

Is it possible to set the package description via config?

I have the following (abridged) configuration in `build.gradle.kts`, I was assuming it would use `pom.description` or the repo's README.md as the description but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```kotlin
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            groupId = project.group.toString()
            artifactId = rootProject.name
            version = project.version.toString()

            from(components["java"])

            pom {
                name.set("steam-webapi-kt")
                description.set("Steam WebAPI wrapper in Kotlin and Ktor")
                url.set("https://github.com/j4ckofalltrades/steam-webapi-kt")
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/j4ckofalltrades/steam-webapi-kt")
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
                password = System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample package: https://github.com/j4ckofalltrades/steam-webapi-kt/packages/899640